# marker (transform: translate(-50, -50)) does not focus on data

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, highcharts

I have the problem with the markers where the images/symbols of the series markers are not centered and reviewing the html properties I find the following

[image]

where the translate of the image contains transform: translate(-50, -50); and when I put transform: translate(0, -50); the marker is centered with its symbol

[image]
[image: Problem]

and I can't find a solution in vue
**Demonstration in codesanbox** : https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-23dqg2?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the translation solution

```
   chart: {
    events: {
        load() {
            const chart = this,
                series = chart.series[0];
                
            series.points.forEach(point => {
                const graphic = point.graphic;
                
                graphic.attr({
                    transform: 'translate(0, 0)'
                });
            })
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that I reported here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18790

As a temporary workaround, you can use the last, correctly working version of Highcharts - `10.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

found a workaround while they fix the bug

in the forum highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50634&p=185227#p185227

Comment: Links may become dead over time. So it would be better to add the most relevant parts of the link directly to the answer.

Comment: Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r64L5ets/